# Query Column Metadata on two different databases

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing a query where I need to query column names in two different databases on the same node. For example, consider the following code snippet:

```
Select * from [db1].sys.columns c1 where OBJECT_NAME(c1.object_id) = 'db1Column'
UNION ALL
Select * from [db2].sys.columns c2 where OBJECT_NAME(c2.object_id) = 'db2Column'
```

If I execute the code above on db1, it only returns rows from the first select. If I change the connection to db2, it only returns rows from the second select. How do I query from *sys.Columns on different databases on the same server in the same query? I've worked around this by using a temp table but it's a messy solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this: `OBJECT_NAME(c1.object_id) =` `OBJECT_NAME` is relative to the database you are connected to, not the database you are querying. Just reference the `[name]` column:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [db1].sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'db1Column'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [db2].sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'db2Column';
```

Comment: Much appreciated response. I still need to use object_id to filter all the columns belonging to a particular table but since you pointed out that it's relative to the DB I changed the call to include the specific database. OBJECT_NAME(c2.object_id, DB_ID('db2')) = 'db2Table'.

Comment: Why do  you "need" `OBJECT_ID` @rallen ? If you want the column's ID, it's also in the table `sys.columns`.

Comment: I use OBJECT_ID to filter for all the columns belonging to a particular table or view. I'm using OBJECT_NAME to convert from the ID to the actual name of the table or view.

Comment: That isn't explained in hyour question at all, @rallen . Why not, instead then, `JOIN` to `sys.tables`?

Comment: Yeah I agree I didn't make the question very clear. I should have put 'db1Table' and 'db2Table'. @Stu suggested joining to sys.tables and filtering by the name column there. I agree that's a better way to do it.

Comment: oh wait nevermind, I'm using OBJECT_NAME because my filters include both views and tables. That way I can specify either without have to include another join.

Comment: `sys.objects` exists too, @rallen ; but you are moving the goal posts now so time for a n ew question .

Answer (score 0):

A bit confused by your usage of `object_name(object_id)` and equating to 'db1column'

`object_name` will return the name of the `table` for that column, so I'm guessing you are wanting to filter rows on a specific table name in multiple databases?

If that's the case you either need to join with `sys.tables`

```
SELECT c.*
from db1.sys.columns c join db1.sys.tables t on t.object_id=c.object_id t.name='table'
union...
```

or just use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns` where you can filter on column or table names

```
select * from db1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where...
union all
select * from db2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where...
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make the example very clear. I was using that function to get all columns for a particular table. I ended up changing the OBJECT_NAME function call to specify the database using DB_ID('db2') as the second parameter after object_id

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the database ID to `OBJECT_NAME`, for example:

```sql
Select * from [db1].sys.columns c1 where OBJECT_NAME(c1.object_id, 5) = 'db1Column'
UNION ALL
Select * from [db2].sys.columns c2 where OBJECT_NAME(c2.object_id, 6) = 'db2Column'
```

But if you want to get it without hardcoding the id, you need to join onto `sys.tables` to get that, at which point you may as well just use `sys.tables.name`:

```sql
Select c1.*
from [db1].sys.columns c1
join [db1].sys.tables t1 on t1.object_id = c1.object_id
where t1.name = 'db1Column'
UNION ALL
Select c2.*
from [db2].sys.columns c2
join [db2].sys.tables t2 on t2.object_id = c2.object_id
where t2.name = 'db2Column'
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I ended up doing based on Larnu's response from earlier: OBJECT_NAME(c2.object_id, DB_ID('db2')) = 'db2Table'